# Close the browser when session expires? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, code-behind

I have an asp.net web page that has a 60 second idle-time window before the session will expire. Is there a way (either through asp, or c# code behind) to close the **browser** - or preferably just the tab - **in the Session_End event?**

I've seen a lot of posts on SO that want to do the opposite (end the session on browser close), but not what I need.

Comment: I think you should abandon this idea...

Comment: You could use a javascript timer.

Comment: Most of the Internet Banking applications uses client side javascript timer and redirect to session expired page.

Comment: @Johnny5 I wish I could but it's a customer request.

Comment: @iamjordanspain that's what I thougt. It's part of our jobs as programmers to explain to customers why they can't do certain things... auto-closing windows can be very annoying to the end user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't close the browser but you can redirect to a "Session Expired" page by doing this:

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        this.PageHead.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
            string.Format("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='{0};url={1}'>", 
            Session.Timeout * 60, "SessionExpired.aspx")));
    }
```

Comment: and what if the user have more than one open windows, and actually the session is keep alive from other window ?

Comment: I have tried that but am having issues running the SessionExpired's Page_Load event.. Whatever code I put in there will work if launched directly but if the page is redirected to, it won't close. Any idea?

Comment: why do want to close the browser? i agree what it would drive a user mad if the browser just closed. you could do `window.close();` in javascript, if you really want to.

Comment: The customer has asked for it specifically to close if left idle. I will try and persuade them to agree to a lock/logout. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can look at this example - [Alert Session Time out in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net)

It basically warn the user before timeout (For example, Bank Of America site). Once it reaches the time limit, redirect user to a logout page.

FYI: User will get mad if you redirect or close a page without warning.